# When limit of derivative of uniformly convergent sequence of functions is equal to derivative of limit function?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Suppose $\{f_n(x)\}\to f(x)$ **[uniformly]** on $X$.

We know we can't claim much about convergence of derivative $\{f'_n(x)\}$, and it may not even be pointwise convergent.

All the counter-examples I have seen till date, appear to have either non-differentiable sequence of functions or pointwise divergent derivatives or non differentiable limit function.

But, what if at some point $x_0$, $\{f'_n(x_0)\}$ converges and $f'(x_0)$ exists. Can we claim that both are equal? If not, is there any strong condition, which can ensure that equality holds?

**EDIT**

After some digging I have found a counterexample  :-
$$f_n(x)= \dfrac { x } { 1 + n ^ { 2 } x ^ { 2 } } \to f(x)=0 \text{ [uniformly] }  \quad \text{for } x\in [-1,1]  $$
$$f _ { n } ^ { \prime } ( x ) = \frac { 1 - n^2x ^ { 2 } } { \left( 1 + n^2x ^ { 2 } \right) ^ { 2 } }$$
Here, $f_n'(0)\to 1 \ne f'(0)$

Still not clear about the second part. Is there any condition, which only need uniform convergence of $\{f_n\}$, pointwise convergence of $f'_n(x_0)$ and existence of $f'(x_0)$, which can ensure that $f'_n(x_0)=f'(x_0)$ ?

Comment: You need uniform convergence of the derivatives, simply because uniform convergence of the functions themselves says nothing about the convergence of the derivatives. If you are interested in $L^p$ convergence of the derivatives, there are some (more advanced) estimates that you could use.

Comment: Please tell us what $X$ is at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

What about $\cos(nx)/n$? We have $\cos(nx)/n\rightrightarrows 0$ everywhere. And $$(\cos(nx)/n)'=\sin(nx).$$
We note that $\sin(n0)\to 0$. However $\sin(nx)\not\rightarrow 0=0'.$

There is a stronger condition that we can use, namely if $f'_n\rightrightarrows g$ on $[a,b]$, and $f_n(x_0)\to c$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x_0\in[a,b],$ then there exists a function $f$ such that $f_n\rightrightarrows f$ on $[a,b]$ and on $[a,b]$ we have $f'=g$. This is Theorem $7.17$ In Rudin's Book Principles of Mathematical Analysis.

Comment: I wanted an example where $f'_n(x)$ is pointwise convergent and $f'(x)$ exists, but both are unequal at some points. $sin(nx)$ is not convergent except at $x=0$.

Comment: @Lord KK, well it is convergent at all multiples of $\pi,$ but I see your point. From your post it seemed if you only wanted convergence at a point. In the case you mention, the answer is still no. Consider the functions $$f_n:=\begin{cases}1-nx&0\leq x\leq1/n\\0&1/n\leq x\leq 1\end{cases}.$$
Now $f_n$ converges pointwise to $1$ at $0$ and $0$ everywhere else. Also $\int_{0}^xf_n(y)dy\rightrightarrows 0,$ However $f_n\not\to 0$.

Comment: That was nice example. Thanks. Can you tell me if there are some conditions, which don't require uniform convergence of derivatives and still limit of derivative coincides with derivative of limit function.

Comment: @Lord KK Thank you. Unfortunately, I don't know any myself. The condition I gave you earlier was the weakest condition I know to ensure that the derivatives coincidence with the derivatives of the limit function. The example I gave shows that even if we have pointwise convergence almost everywhere of the derivatives, it doesn't guarantee us pointwise convergence everywhere. I don't know what other conditions to apply. Sorry.